# I have a ded circ for my fridge with 2 neutrals attached to the receptacle. 1 of the neutrals is shared with 2 other cir. Can I remove the shared?

Tags: electrical

I have 3 circuits - 2 20 amp and 1 15 amp.  1 20 amp is dedicated to the Fridge and the receptacle for the fridge has the hot from the panel terminated at the receptacle and also has a neutral from the panel terminated at the receptacle.  Additionally, the receptacle has a second neutral attached.  The second neutral pigtails from the receptacle and branch off and serves as a shared neutral for the 15 amp circuit and the other 20 amp.  Is this necessary?  Can I disconnect the shared neutral from the receptacle, leaving the single neutral for the receptacle?

Comment: You are not suppose to share neutrals between circuits(one hot, one neutral).  Wire costs money, and sounds like something funny(bad) is going on here.  Does each of the other two circuits have matching neutrals to their hots at the panel?  Do you have conduit pipes for your circuits or just cables?

Comment: No, the other two circuits are sharing the second neutral that is also attached to the receptacle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's completely insane! The previous person did not know how to wire a house.

### Neutral current = hot current

Current flows in loops.  Power must go out one wire and come back another wire.  Now on vehicles you can use the chassis for return, but not in AC power wiring.  Every circuit is wired as a whole loop - out and back. The current is the same on the whole loop. Every hot has a partner neutral for a return.

With AC wiring, we tend to run it at thermal limits.  I.E. we can't put any more current on it or the wire will overheat and start a fire.  That means the neutral wire will have the same current as the hot wire, and it will be pushing thermal limits same as the hot.

**And neutrals don't have breakers!** There's no reason to need a breaker on neutral, since it can't possibly carry more current than its partner hot..... *right?*

Right?

Of course, this depends on careful match-up so that each neutral serves only its partner hot.

So if 3 circuits share a neutral, they are trying to set the neutral wire on fire.  Nothing will prevent this.

### One exception that is OK

Due to the unique split-phase system used in North American influenced areas (including Brazil and Japan), the neutral is actually located between two (sometimes 3) hot wires.  That is, one hot wire is +120V, and the other one is -120V.  (at certain moments; this is AC power so the polarity will reverse very shortly).

It is possible to have what's called a "Multi-Wire Branch Circuit" (MWBC) where opposite-phase hots share a neutral. Sketch it out on paper, but neutral only ends up handling difference current, and that can never exceed max circuit current.

However there are rules for MWBCs:

- The two hot wires (rarely, in 3-phase power zones such as NYC or Brazil, 3 hot wires) must be on a "common throw" breaker with a handle tie.
- Voltages must be opposite: if you measure "hot vs hot" voltage you must get 240V (or rarely, 208V or 220V, looking at you Brazil).
- The neutral must be pigtailed!  You can never use a device like a socket for a neutral splice, because if someone removed that device, that would break neutral for the other hot wire.

It's remotely possible that 2 of these wires are a correctly configured MWBC.  However MWBCs play badly with GFCI and AFCI, and so the trend is to move away from them.

Every standard cable comes with enough neutral wires. So I don't understand why they're not using the neutral wires they got 'for free'.  If this is in conduit, where you can fish individual wires, then simply fish more neutral wires (remember you must mark them to show which hot they are associated with).  If this is cable, watch out for them doing something even worse, like using white for a hot and bootlegging ground for a neutral.  The ground wire is sometimes smaller than the neutral needs to be. And it's not properly insulated!

Comment: Can you have a MWBC with a 15 and 20 amp breaker? OP said one 20, one 15, and one other 20.  I imagine that is a no-no.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, as you all have confirmed my thinking on this.  I will remove the shared neutral from the receptacle and consider running wire to eliminate the MWBC.

Comment: And yes, it is conduit.

Comment: @crip659 you can have a 15/20 MWBC, but you will need #12 neutral and will need to "build your own" breaker with handle ties. No one makes a pre-built 15/20 breaker with handle ties, so 120V loads only.

Comment: @Dennis 3 legs of an MWBC sharing a neutral is illegal/overload. The only way that works is a 3-phase MWBC which requires 3-phase 120/208 (or Brazil 127/220) power.  Regardless, you should keep the fridge independent, don't want something else tripping it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine  Thank you, did not know if 15/20 MWBC was a thing.